# Why is gadolinium specifically used in MRI contrast agents?

Tags: biochemistry, nmr-spectroscopy, magnetism, rare-earth-elements

Gadolinium(III) chelate complexes are routinely used as [contrast agents in magnetic resonance imaging (MRI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MRI_contrast_agent);<sup>1</sup> the usual explanation is that paramagnetic species contain unpaired electrons, which cause relaxation of nearby $\ce{^1H}$ nuclei.

**Why gadolinium, and not any of the other lanthanides?**

In particular, $\ce{Tb^3+/Dy^3+/Ho^3+/Er^3+}$ have [magnetic moments](https://www.radiochemistry.org/periodictable/la_series/L8.html) that are larger than that of $\ce{Gd^3+}$ (due to orbital angular momentum). At first glance, these should possess even higher relaxivity, since the rate of relaxation due to random fields is proportional to $\langle B_\mathrm{loc}^2 \rangle$.<sup>2</sup>

I do vaguely recall reading one sentence, about the fact that ground states that aren't S terms are not spherically symmetric, and there's some problem associated with this. But I can't find the reference anymore and I don't remember any other detail.

---

*References*

1. Werner, E. J.; Datta, A.; Jocher, C. J.; Raymond, K. N. High-Relaxivity MRI Contrast Agents: Where Coordination Chemistry Meets Medical Imaging. *Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.* **2008,** *47* (45), 8568–8580. [DOI: 10.1002/anie.200800212](https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.200800212).
2. Hore, P. J. *Nuclear Magnetic Resonance,* 2nd ed.; Oxford University Press: Oxford, U.K., 2015; pp 65, 71.

Comment: Probably medical/economical reasons.

Comment: With very limited knowledge in this subject, I recommend reading a review 'Alternatives to Gadolinium-Based Metal Chelates for Magnetic Resonance Imaging' (*Chem. Rev.*, $2010$, 110 (5), pp 2960–3018, DOI: [10.1021/cr900284a](https://doi.org/10.1021/cr900284a)). It is also freely available as a manuscript [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2874212/). Sections $3$ and $5$ should be especially pertinent. It specifically discusses $\ce{Gd^3+}$ vs other $\ce{Ln^3+}$ complexes.

Comment: You see a lot more variety in situations where people aren't bothered if the animal survives long term.. I think in human cases its simply that the Gd systems have been through trials and aren't horrendously toxic/can just about be gotten rid of by the body

Comment: I found [this section on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanthanide#Magnetic_and_spectroscopic) after a short browse: *"The maximum number of unpaired electrons is 7, in $\ce{Gd^{3+}}$, with a magnetic moment of 7.94 B.M., but the largest magnetic moments, at 10.4–10.7 B.M., are exhibited by $\ce{Dy^{3+}}$ and $\ce{Ho^{3+}}$. However, in $\ce{Gd^{3+}}$ all the electrons have parallel spin and this property is important for the use of gadolinium complexes as contrast reagent in MRI scans."*

Answer (score 11):

The reasons may possibly be:

- T<sub>1</sub> shortening
- Relatively less adverse reactions
- Increased contrast enhancement

> The most commonly used clinically approved contrast agents for MR
> imaging are gadolinium-based compounds that produce **T<sub>1</sub> shortening**.

Tissue relaxation results from interactions between the unpaired electron of gadolinium and tissue hydrogen protons, which significantly decrease the T<sub>1</sub> of the blood relative to the surrounding tissues.

Additionally, **adverse reactions to this agent are far less frequent** than those seen with iodinated compounds, with common reactions including nausea, vomiting, headache, paresthesias, or dizziness.

> T<sub>1</sub>weighted sequences are part of almost all MRI protocols and are
> best thought of as the most 'anatomical' of images, resulting in
> images that most closely approximate the appearances of tissues
> macroscopically, although even this is a gross simplification.

[image]

*Figure 1-10. MR enterography on a patient with Crohn disease. A. Coronal T<sub>2</sub>-weighted image shows wall thickening
and stenotic ileum (arrow). B. Coronal gadolinium-enhanced fat suppressed T<sub>1</sub>-weighted image shows increased
contrast enhancement of one thickened segment of ileum (arrow).*

*Credits Basic Radiology Chapter 1 page 11*

**Update**

Most of the answer above was based on pharmacological/medical aspects but some chemistry aspects have been included below:

Also the article mentioned by@Linear Christmas contains valuable information on the subject

**Contrast agents**

> Contrast agents can be divided into two groups depending on whether
> they cause changes in either T<sub>1</sub> (longitudinal relaxation – in simple
> terms, the time taken for the protons to realign with the external
> magnetic field) or T<sub>2</sub> (transverse relaxation – in simple terms, the
> time taken for the protons to exchange energy with other nuclei)
> relaxation rates of the water protons, these being known as positive
> or negative agents respectively.
>
> The ability of an agent to affect T<sub>1</sub> and T<sub>2</sub>is characterised by the
> concentration-normalised relaxivities r<sub>1</sub> and r<sub>2</sub>respectively. These
> parameters refer to the amount of increase in 1/T<sub>1</sub> and 1/T<sub>2</sub>
> respectively, per millimole of agent, and are normally quoted as a
> rate (mM21 s21).4 The values are used to determine the efficiency of a
> contrast agent, and they consist of contributions from both inner
> sphere and outer sphere relaxation mechanisms Negative contrast agents
> influence the signal intensity by shortening transverse relaxation
> (T<sub>2</sub>), thereby producing darker images as high T<sub>2</sub> results in increased
> brightness of the images.

**Gadolinium (III) vs other lanthanide (III) ions**

> Gadolinium(III) reagents are commonly focused on, due to the coupling
> of a large magnetic moment with a long electron spin relaxation time
> of $\ce10^{-9}$s  at the magnetic field strengths used in MRI
> techniques.

Gadolinium (III) ion is unique in a number of respects:

It has the ability to shorten both the longitudinal and transverse relaxation times of water protons approximately to the same extent by relaxing all nearby protons. Other Ln(III) ions with large magnetic moments are less efficient in shortening T<sub>1</sub>.

> The gadolinium ion is also unique among other Ln(III) because its
> symmetric seven electron ground state results in an electronic
> relaxation rate that is **six orders of magnitude slower** than the
> other Ln(III) ions. This in turn results in a strong magnetic
> anisotropy and fast electronic relaxation states with very short T<sub>1</sub>,
> on the order of $\ce10^{-13}$s.

Other Ln (III) ions tend to undergo Curie relaxation enhancement arising from the interaction of the nuclear spin with the thermal average of the electron spin. (The Curie-spin relaxation effect is significant at lower temperatures and **higher magnetic fields** and for ions with a large magnetic moment).

It has been observed that the Curie spin relaxation effect affects the transverse relaxation more than the longitudinal relaxation. Consequently paramagnetic Ln(III) other than Gd (III) are less efficient T<sub>1</sub> relaxation agents.

**Use of other Lanthanide (III) ions as MRI contrast agents**

Dysprosium(III) is another lanthanide ion that has been used in
MRI, being classed as a negative contrast agent. In the use of high magnetic fields,

> Gd(III) based contrast agents exhibit poor water relaxivity. As a
> result, the interest in dysprosium-based complexes is increasing as
> they display slow water exchange, due to the need to lengthen the
> residence time in order to optimise the r<sub>2</sub> relaxivity. Dy(III) has a
> large magnetic susceptibility which induces local field gradients
> resulting in a lowering of T<sub>2</sub>.

Generally, dysprosium complexes where the water molecules have a long residence time, possess potential application as negative contrast agents
at high magnetic fields due to their efficient transverse relaxivity. However it has been demonstrated that lengthening the residence time of water can actually be detrimental, because the transverse relaxivity
can then be limiting.

The overall conclusion from the use of dysprosium(III)
complexes as contrast agents is that due to the balancing of
factors required to optimise r<sub>2</sub>, design of a suitable molecular
structure is crucial. Fine tuning these residence times of the
water protons, and hence the relaxivity, may lead to promising
contrast agents for high field magnetic resonance imaging.

> Europium(II) analogues have been proposed as alternatives to Gd(III)
> because they are isoelectronic—each having seven unpaired electrons.

The only problem with this complex was that the stability of the Eu(II) chelate was 107 times higher than that of the Eu(III) chelate, which
meant that the Eu(III) complex could be susceptible to dissociation, possibly releasing toxic Eu(III) into the body.

**Other strongly paramagnetic ions e.g Tb(III), Ho(III), Er(III) can have significant effect on line widths and such line broadening usually makes it difficult or even impossible to detect nuclei that are located within a certain distance of the lanthanide ion.**

There is still promising use of other Lanthanide (III) compounds as contrast agents as alternatives to using T<sub>1</sub> shortening contrast agents as contrast can originate from altering proton density or the total water signal that is detected (using another technique called Magnetisation Transfer (MT). In this case gadolinium(III) cannot be used in this technique because the T<sub>1</sub> of water would be too short, but other lanthanides, such as Eu(III), can be used because they have smaller magnetic moments, relaxing bulk water much less efficiently.

Other potential candidates are still being tested under laboratory conditions, contrast agents used in the body clearly should be biocompatible, but there are also other requisites need to be addressed as well. These include the requirements of rapid renal excretion, water solubility, stability in aqueous conditions, and a low osmotic potential when in solution for clinical work.

**References**

- Basic Radiology Michael Y. M. Chen, MD
- 'Alternatives to Gadolinium-Based Metal Chelates for Magnetic Resonance Imaging' (Chem. Rev., 20102010, 110 (5), pp 2960–3018,
- Lanthanides in magnetic resonance imaging. Melanie Bottrill, Lilian Kwok and Nicholas J. Long
  Chemistry Society Reviews, DOI: 10.1039/b516376p